# MacOSX Console Application to slow or speedup speech without losing quality

Tags: macos, avaudioengine

I have a .mp3 file that contains just voice and I would like to adjust the speed (slower or faster) while maintaining the same clarity. No chipmunks! Then write out the modified file to disk. In order to do this, I am trying to use the AVAudioEngine Framework but am a complete N00B to the framework. All the examples, I have found, are geared to modifying music or recording voice then playing it audibly. I just want to convert to a different speed and have it spit out the modified file. This was all I could figure out so far, I documented my confusion in the comments of the code.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

print("Change Voice Speed")

let engine = AVAudioEngine()
let speedControl = AVAudioUnitVarispeed()
let originalFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/User/Desktop/speech.mp3")

do {
   // What do I do with the input file ?
   let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: originalFile)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("There's an error: \(error)")
}

speedControl.rate += 0.1
engine.attach(speedControl)
// Do I need to attach a AVAudioRecorder and record here ?

print("Write New File")

let outputFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/User/Desktop/modifiedSpeech.mp3")


// Don't know what settings to put for a .mp3 file are. Also not
// sure if this actually writes the file to disk

do {
   try AVAudioFile(forWriting: outputFile, settings: <#T##[String : Any]#>)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("There's an error: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is proof-of-concept code that speeds up a stereo M4A file and saves it as a WAVE file. There is minimal error handling and no attempt at handling different channel layouts, but hopefully it should get you started:

```swift
let engine = AVAudioEngine()

// Use AVAudioUnitTimePitch to avoid pitch shifts
let timePitch = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()

engine.attach(timePitch)
engine.attach(player)

engine.connect(player, to:timePitch, format: nil)
engine.connect(timePitch, to:engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

// Speed up the file 1.5x
timePitch.rate = 1.5

// Run the engine in manual rendering mode using chunks of 512 frames
let renderSize: AVAudioFrameCount = 512

let renderFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 44100.0, channels: 2, interleaved: true)!
let renderBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: renderFormat, frameCapacity: renderSize)!

try! engine.enableManualRenderingMode(.offline, format: renderFormat, maximumFrameCount: renderBuffer.frameCapacity)

try! engine.start()
player.play()

// The render format is also the output format
let output = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/foo.wav"), settings: renderFormat.settings, commonFormat: renderFormat.commonFormat, interleaved: renderFormat.isInterleaved)
let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/test.m4a"))

// Read using a buffer sized to produce `renderSize` frames of output
let readSize = AVAudioFrameCount(Float(renderSize) * timePitch.rate)
let readBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: file.processingFormat, frameCapacity: readSize)!

// Process the file
while true {
    do {
        // Processing is finished if all frames have been read
        if file.framePosition == file.length {
            break
        }

        try file.read(into: readBuffer)
        player.scheduleBuffer(readBuffer, completionHandler: nil)

        let result = try engine.renderOffline(renderBuffer.frameCapacity, to: renderBuffer)

        // Try to avoid adding silence
        let expectedFrames = AVAudioFrameCount(Float(readBuffer.frameLength) / timePitch.rate)
        if expectedFrames < renderBuffer.frameLength {
            renderBuffer.frameLength = expectedFrames
        }

        // Write the adjusted-rate audio
        try output.write(from: renderBuffer)
        if result != .success {
            break
        }
    }
    catch {
        break
    }
}

player.stop()
engine.stop()
```